# Unexpected results appear when using time filters instead of sprint (during, before, after)

Tags: jira, jql

So I have these 3 filters that seem to work if I use `sprint = ###`, it's a total issues, open issues, and a closed issues. And the open and closed issues always add up to the total.
But when I try the same thing using during (which I need to use to get a graphing plugin to work) I get some unexpected results.

So for example this version of my filter will return 11 results:

```
Project = EX AND assignee was example.user  DURING ('2018/02/07', '2018/03/05')
```

But the filter for open issues is returning 6 results.

```
 Project = EX AND assignee was example.user AND status was not in (DONE, CLOSED) DURING ('2018/02/07', '2018/03/05')
```

But closed only gets 2:

```
 Project = EX AND assignee was example.user AND status was in (DONE, CLOSED) DURING ('2018/02/07', '2018/03/05')
```

So instead of it matching the total, open and closed issues only add up to 8 of what should be 11. Even more confusing is on some periods the graphing tool gets more open issues than it gets total issues.

Note:
It also does it if I use `DURING (endOfDay(-11),endOfDay(3))` or `after "2018/02/07" before "2018/03/05". But really I need it to work with some sort of during due to the tool I'm trying to integrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DURING statement only applies to the last statement made before it.

Meaning that in your first filter you search for issues that were assigned to your example.user during that period.

In the second filter you search for issues that were ever assigned to your example.user and were in the statuses you specify in the period in the DURING statement. So the during will only check the status, not the assignee.

Same goes for the thrid statement.

Hope this helps

Comment: You're right. Do you know any way I can combine the two statements? 
It seems `assignee was example.user DURING (x', x') AND status was not in (DONE, CLOSED) DURING (x', x')` would work, but do to the way the plugin works I can't do this.  But `(assignee was example.user AND status was not in (DONE, CLOSED)) DURING (x', x')`. doesn't work, is there a way to use during on an AND statement?